# Delete market history

Tags: android

My task is to clear/delete market history programmatically. I searched and found that  deleting **"/data/data/com.android.vending/databases/suggestions.db"** will do the task but no access to this location.

Please let me know is there any way to grant access to this location or any other way to clear market history programmatically. I dont have a rooted device.

Thanks

Comment: To grant access root the phone

Comment: I know rooting will give the access to the specified path but I want to clear market history without rooting.

Answer (score 1):

Files belonging to one application are inaccessible to others unless they've been explicitly marked world-readable (or, in some very, very rare cases, world-writable).

The only way for you to clear the history would be for the Market application to offer an intent that does so.  It doesn't, so the short answer is that you can't do it programmatically.

Comment: I understand what you reply. Lots of free application are available in the market that provides the option to clear market history so I think there must be some other way.

Comment: I am waiting for experts comment.